# Strange error about invalid syntax

Tags: python

I am getting invalid syntax error in my python script for this statement

```
44 f = open(filename, 'r')
45 return

 return
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure what exactly is wrong here? I am a python newbie and so will greatly appreciate if someone can please help.

I am using version 2.3.4

Comment: Check the indentation  for mixture of tabs and spaces.

Comment: @user: Show us some more code otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: -1: Not enough context to do anything more than guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting "invalid syntax" on a plain return statement is pretty much impossible. If you use it outside of a function, you get `'return' outside function`, if you have the wrong indentation you get `IndentationError`, etc.

The only way I can get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on a return statement, is if in fact it doesn't say `return` at all, but if it contains non-ascii characters, such as `retürn`. That give this error. Now, how can you have that error without seeing it? Again, the only idea I can come up with is that you in fact have indentation, but that this indentation is not spaces or tabs. You can for example have somehow inserted a non-breaking space in your code.

Yes, this can happen. Yes, I have had that happen to me. Yes, you get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" can also happen if you have parens above the return statement that you forgot to close.

Comment: It can also happen if you forget the second half of a statement requiring two parts, like having a `try:` without having an `except:`

Comment: Thanks @erjiang. Your comment bailed me out after several minutes of checking. I get a SyntaxError because I had one parens missing.

Comment: @erijang you should add your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 35):

I had the same problem. Here was my code:

```
def gccontent(genomefile):
    nbases = 0
    totalbases = 0
    GC = 0
    for line in genomefile.xreadlines():
        nbases += count(seq, 'N')
        totalbases += len(line)
        GC += count(line, 'G' or 'C')
    gcpercent = (float(GC)/(totalbases - nbases)*100
    return gcpercent
```

'return'was invalid syntax

I simply failed to close the bracket on the following code:

```
gcpercent = (float(GC)/(totalbases - nbases)*100
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

I got an "Invalid Syntax" on return when I forgot to close the bracket on my code.

```
elif year1==year2 and month1 != month2:
    total_days = (30-day1)+(day2)+((month2-(month1+1))*30   
    return (total_days)
```

Invalid syntax on return.

```
((month2-(month1+1))*30  <---- there should be another bracket

((month2-(month1+1)))*30
```

Now my code works.

They should improve python to tell you if you forgot to close your brackets instead of having an "invalid" syntax on return.

Comment: My problem was not with return, but the cause was a missing bracket in the prior clause. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5):

I just looked this up because I was having the same problem (invalid syntax error on plain return statement), and I am extremely new at python (first month) so I have no idea what I'm doing most of the time.

Well I found my error, I had forgotten an ending parentheses on the previous line. Try checking the end of the previous line for a forgotten parentheses or quote?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 45 return
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    45 return
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

That might explain it.  It doesn't explain the `44 f = open(filename, 'r')`, but I suspect that someone copied and pasted 45 lines of code where the indentation was lost and line numbers included.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's a parenthetical syntax error. Check around the error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem by trying to return a simple variable assignation within an "if" block.

```
    elif len(available_spots)==0:
    return score=0
```

That would give me a syntax error. I fixed it simply by adding a statement before the return

```
 elif len(available_spots)==0:
    score=0
    return score
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue in my case was, that i mixed up datatypes in my return statement. E.g.

```
return string + list + string
```